# Laravel Envoy: abort on error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-envoy

Is it possible to abort on errors or call another task when a command fails?

This doesn't work:

```
@task('migrate', ['on' => 'web'])
    cd {{ $currentReleaseDir }};
    php artisan migrate || exit 1;
@endtask
```

It fails with the message (I know I can run `--force`, it's just a way to make the command fail for testing):

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************
```

But then it proceeds to run the rest of the deploy script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
@error
   echo $task;
   exit; /*Or Do any other processing*/
@enderror
```

this outputs

```
<?php $__container->error(function($task) {
    echo $task;
    exit; /*Or Do any other processing*/
}); ?>
```

This is listed in the compiler functions here https://github.com/laravel/envoy/blob/master/src/Compiler.php